# Get value of DataContext Result column by variable name

Tags: c#, datacontext, system.reflection

I've been searching and playing around with GetType() for a while, but I keep getting the name of the column (which I already have) and not the value.

I'm trying to build a csv file from the results of a method (stored procedure call) in a datacontext.

I'm fine up to figuring out how to dynamically grab result.some_column_name from the result set.

```
using (SomeDataContext ctx = new SomeDataContext())
        {
        List<Some_MethodResult> results = ctx.Get_Some_Method(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3).ToList();

        var colnames = ctx.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(typeof(SomeDataContext)).GetMetaType(typeof(Get_Some_MethodResult)).DataMembers;


        foreach (Get_Some_MethodResult r in results)
        {
            foreach (var colname in colnames)
            {
                string line = "\"" + r.GetType().GetField(colname.Name).ToString() + "\",";
                sb.Append(line);
            }
         }
```

The above gets me the name of the field, and I'm looking for the value.  GetMember() doesn't seem to get me any better results.

I'm still looking to see if I can find out the right way to dynamically refer to a column by column name, but if this is simple and just a non-often-asked question, I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Save the result of `GetField` and call `GetValue` on it, passing `r` as the parameter.

But you don't want to be calling `GetField` inside a nested loop.  Loop through the columns once, saving all the `GetField()` results into a `FieldInfo[]` array.  Then inside your nested loops, fetch from the array.

If that isn't performant enough, you can use an expression tree to build a `Func<Get_Some_MethodResult, object>` from each field that accesses that field on any arbitrary object, and save an array of those instead of `FieldInfo`.  (For properties, this was possible using `GetGetMethod` and `CreateDelegate` before expression trees).  Then you wouldn't need any reflection at all inside the nested loops.

---

Of course, all of this complexity might be avoided if you skipped over your ORM mapping and just processed the `IDataReader` that came back from the stored procedure.  A data reader provides easy indexed access to both column values and values.

It's really quite trivial to write a function that turns any `IDataReader` into CSV.

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  GetField wasn't the place I should have been looking, apparently.  I'll add my answer shortly.

Comment: @adrianstovall: In your question, you said you did get the name back from `GetField(colname.Name).ToString()`.  Are you now saying that the code in the question did NOT get the name?

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer has a couple of parts to it.  Kudos to my co-worker Tony Colich for helping me learn on this one.

First, it's GetProperties() and not GetFields() that I should have been looking at for the column values returned by the sproc.

Knowing that helped immensely.  The new loop looks like (please ignore the colval/boolean bit):

```
using (SomeDataContext ctx = new SomeDataContext())
        {
        List<Some_MethodResult> results = ctx.Get_Some_Method(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3).ToList();

        var colnames = ctx.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(typeof(SomeDataContext)).GetMetaType(typeof(Get_Some_MethodResult)).DataMembers;

        var props = typeof(Get_Some_MethodResult).GetProperties().Where(p => colnames.Any(n => p.Name == n.Name));

        foreach (Get_Some_MethodResult r in results)
        {
            foreach (var colname in colnames)
            {
                bool firstcol = true;
                foreach (var colname in colnames)
                {
                    var prop = props.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == colname.Name);
                    if (prop != null)
                    {
                        string colval = "";
                        if (!firstcol)
                        {
                            colval = ",\"" + prop.GetValue(r, null).ToString() + "\"";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            colval = "\"" + prop.GetValue(r, null).ToString() + "\"";
                        }
                        //var field =
                        sb.Append(colval);
                        firstcol = false;
                    }
                }
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
         }
```

Now, as far as whether or not I should have done this at all, there are only so many hours to spend on a project sometimes, and this was the path of least resistance.  Thanks to all who responded!

Comment: You really should use `GetGetMethod()` which I mentioned in my answer, and do that outside the nested loops (`GetProperties()` and `GetGetMethod()` need reflection which is very expensive).  Do it just once, and then reuse the getter method on each successive row of results.